# Automated 301 redirect for any missing pages within specific directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to help a friend move a Wordpress site to a new server. However, it has many old blog pages that he'd like to have deleted.

Instead of doing a 301 redirect for each and every blog that is about to be deleted back to the blog main page, is there a way to automatically create a 301 redirect for any of the missing pages of that directory only?

For example, any page that does not exist at www.website.com/blog/... would be automatically redirected to www.website.com/blog/ (not homepage)

However, for any other page such as www.website.com/otherdirectory/... would be treated as a regular 404 page.

Hope this makes sense.

We have Urban Giraffe's Redirection plugin installed for one off redirects already. Would be super if the other blogs to be deleted could be fully automated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found my own answer (sort of) - hope this can help others:

Auto Redirect 404 in 301 for Trashed Posts
http://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-redirect-404/

There are a few caveats though. This plugin monitors what you are about to delete and then automatically creates a 301 redirect. Note that this does not help with already deleted posts.

Note that I have installed this, but I have now removed it after doing all of the deletions. Once I deleted all the unnecessary posts, it created a list of the 301's. I have copied this list then imported them into the Plugin below so that it can be managed by 1 plugin. Also, the issue I have with this plugin is that it also monitors media and pages. This means that if you delete a page (ie ...com/test/) it will make a redirect - however, if you create a page again later with the same URL (ie ...com/test/) that page will no longer be visible as the redirect has been created in a table of your database. This plugin does *NOT* let you undo a redirect. If you deactivate the plugin, the 301's will stop working so that is the only way to stop the redirects. All or nothing.

To manage other 301's and to turn on and off redirections for single pages, I use:

Wordpress Redirection:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

This will allow you to add 301's for other urls.  This also allows you to import a CSV. I have created a CSV with the list created with the above Plugin and imported into this for better management.

I have also turned off "monitoring" in the options section (Don't monitor) so that it will not accidentally create a bunch of unnecessary redirects. For example, if you create a blog post with this url: ...com/test/ and change it to ...com/test2/ it will automatically create a redirect. This means that later in the future, if you create a page ...com/test/ you will not be able to view it. It will always redirect to ...com/test2/. This kind of automation can be troubling if you forget this monitoring is on.

Hope this helps.

If anyone knows of a better way to automate any missing page from a particular directory, please let me know.